# Find a limit of a sum

Tags: limits, riemann-sum

Can anyone help me with the problem:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty }  \sum_{k=0}^{2n}  \frac{k}{k + n^{2} } $

In the hints it's adviced to make a Riemann sum from it and calculate the integral but i don't know how to do it

Comment: (Adapting the solution of the question linked above from $\sum_{k=1}^n$ to $\sum_{k=1}^{2n}$ is straightforward.) However, I don't think there is a direct way (without some inequalities beforehand) to cast this as a Riemann sum.

Comment: @ClementC., okay, thank you

Comment: The reason for the last part of my comment: you have $k+n^2$ in the denominator. Because of that square, you cannot massage that to get something as a function of $\frac{k}{2n}$ only.

Comment: @ClementC:  You can do this as $\lim_n \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \frac{k}{n^2+k} = \lim_n \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{k/n}{1+k/n^2} = \lim_n \lim_m \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{k/n}{1+k/(nm)}  =  \lim_n \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{2n}(k/n) = \int_0^2 x \, dx = 2$.  Using the double limit is valid here since the inner limit is approached uniformly for all $n$. This works for a large class of such almost-Riemann sums.

Comment: @RRL That's (1) a lot more involved than what Riemann sum exercises usually presume, and (2) actually, once you get there and had to argue about uniform confergence, double-limit swapping, etc., what is the point of a Riemann sum anyway in this exercise? $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{k}{n}$ has a straightforward closed-form.

Comment: No point except the last limit is not always amenable to evaluation other than as a Riemann sum -- and that has arisen here before.